# I am looking for a way to change the tooltip background color in slickgrid

Tags: tooltip, slickgrid

Is there a way to change the tooltip background and text color in slick grid.  Currently, I have a formatter in column that looks like this
return { text: '', toolTip: dataContext.documentComments };

When I hover over the icon the tooltip background is black.  How can I change the background color? I have tried every css trick/override known to man with no resolve.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is just a regular browser tooltip, it adds a `title` to the container. If you want to style the tooltip, which I don't think you can on the default browser tooltip, you'll need to use a 3rd party lib like tipsy, bootstrap  or whatever else.

Comment: I have tried every override in bootstrap and ngBootstrap something is just not allowing the background to change.